# Why is console empty even on printing characters?

Tags: dart

Here's a simple dart code which I've been trying out at https://dartpad.dev .

```dart
void main(){  
  var numbers = new List(10);
  for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
    numbers[i] = i;
  }
  print(numbers[1]);
  print("hello world");
}
```

Why is console empty? It doesn't print `1` or `hello world` . What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has an `index out of range error`, that is when you are using `i<=10`, you get this.

> 1. Since, in your initialization of the `List numbers`, you have the length as `10`, but due to `i<=10`, it will store the length of `11`. **Hence error.**
> 2. The code will go from `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`, which is in total `11` in number. *INDEX OUT OF RANGE ERROR*

```
Uncaught Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 10: 10
```

You just need to make the data as this: `i<10`, if you don't want the error. Else, use `i=1; i<11` => `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

```
void main(){  
  var numbers = new List(10);
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    numbers[i] = i;
  }
  print(numbers[1]);
  print("hello world");
}
```

**Output**

```
1
hello world
```

Comment: Cool. Still wondering why dartpad didn't show such obvious error in the console.

Comment: Might be some glitch. I tested it out on my computer only @SauravPathak You can always check on your local box as well, when this doesn't work out :)